# Update a scss variable from Angular Service

Tags: angular, sass

I have a _color.scss file. I have a $primaryImageURL which stores the location of an image. Is it possible to update this variable from an Angular Service. I fetch the location details from a get call from my angular service. 
An image gets uploaded from another service and Am trying to update the location of the primary image dynamically.

```
// _color.scss
$primaryImageURL = 'src/assets/img/primaryImage.png';

//Service
someService.getPrimaryColor().subscribe(data => {
  const brandingImg = data.brandImgUrl;
  // Need to update $primaryImageURL here dynamically. 
});
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update a SCSS variable from an Angular variable. SCSS is being compiled during the build to a CSS file. What you can do is store the primary image url into one variable in the component and then bind it via [src]="...".